# difference between firebase app indexing and app links

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-app-indexing

I am working on one project in that, I need to implement something so that when user search for our website it shows a icon of app besides name of the website in google app.

Further more user can redirect directly to app if he has installed the app.

Here I got confusion between firebase app indexing and app links(Android studio 2.3 tool). Can any one suggest me which tool I need to use to implement this feature and why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**App Indexing** actually uses the deep-link kind method but helps you to achieve the different goal. In a simple business scenario, you would want if the user searches for your business from mobile browser he should get app link and that link open different screens for different URLs (search keywords). As you can see the post so far talks about keywords, searches that mean App Indexing is more about search engine optimization keeping mobile apps in mind and App Search Optimization too.

About **deep-links** they are simple URLs (or URL set) that we define in our app and tell the mobile system that if matching URL is clicked our App can also handle it.

In case of deep-link there can be several apps claiming to open same
URL but app indexing result will open only your app.

I hope this answer clarifies things well.

Check this for more specific solution
[App Indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/), [Deep linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html) and [this](https://www.bruceclay.com/blog/apps-101-what-is-deep-linking-and-app-indexing-setup/)

Comment: copy paste from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024456/what-is-the-difference-between-app-indexing-and-deep-linking

Comment: I have added the links from where I got this details. cheers!

Answer (score 5):

**Firebase App Indexing:**

> Firebase App Indexing gets your app into Google Search. If users have
>   your app installed, they can launch your app and go directly to the
>   content they're searching for.
>
> To get your app's content indexed by Google, use the same URLs in your
>   app that you use on your website and verify that you own both your app
>   and your website. Google Search crawls the links on your website and
>   serves them in Search results.

**Firebase Dynamic Links:**

> Firebase Dynamic Links are links that work the way you want, on
>   multiple platforms, and whether or not your app is already installed.
>
> With Dynamic Links, your users get the best available experience for
>   the platform they open your link on. If a user opens a Dynamic Link on
>   iOS or Android, they can be taken directly to the linked content in
>   your native app. If a user opens the same Dynamic Link in a desktop
>   browser, they can be taken to the equivalent content on your website.

Firebase Dynamic Links Use Cases:

The following use cases are some of the ways you can use Dynamic Links in your app to drive growth and engagement.

1. Converting web users to app users
2. Social, email, and SMS campaigns
3. User-to-user sharing
4. Converting desktop users to app users
5. Real-world app promotion

Checkout more detail at [Firebase Dynamic Links Use Cases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/)

I hope, it clear your confusion between firebase app indexing and dynamic links.

Comment: From my understanding we are not able to make mobile Google Search result Dynamic Link even if it's App Link, right? I don't see such Use Case, but this is what I would expect from such "revolutionary" tool.

Answer (score 2):

They use for different purposes:

1. **Firebase App Indexing** gets your app into Google Search.
2. **Firebase Dynamic Links** use a single link to work on multiple platforms, whether your app is already installed or not.

They best way is to use both of them, so you can create a single link for each content in your website, it can be opened smoothly in iOS, Android and PC browser.