# Android Deep Links and App Links Confused

Tags: android, android-permissions, deep-linking, applinks, android-app-indexing

Can anyone explain in real life example what is the difference between

App Links - https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

Deep links - https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

App Indexing - https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html

**in Android?**

Have read too many posts and documentations, but still cannot get the exact gist.

I understand that App links works with Android 6.0 and Deep Links with 4.2. but in performance, they are doing the similar task.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45173210/3983054

Comment: if you look to the question given, there is asked to give a life example and also App indexing. in your link provided, it is stated only APP links and Deep links. please be more concise @King of Masses

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If you have an app or are developing an app, app indexation and deep
>   linking are things you definitely need to be paying attention to.
>   Basically, Google wants to treat your app like a website. It wants to
>   crawl it and index it so that search results can return specific pages
>   from an app in mobile searches. That ability to return specific pages
>   within an app? That’s deep linking.

**What is Deep Linking?**

> Deep linking, in a general sense, involves linking to specific content
>   within a website or app, rather than to the homepage. Here we’re
>   talking in particular about getting specific elements of an app to
>   show up in search results on a mobile device, allowing users to open
>   an app directly from a search results page. Note: Users will only see
>   this prompt if they have the particular app installed.

Photo: [image: Example]

**What Is App Indexing?**

> App indexing is the result of getting your app in Google’s index to
>   enable deep linking. By allowing Google to index pages within your
>   app, features (or promotions) within the app can begin showing up in
>   users’ mobile searches, driving visits (and hopefully conversions) to
>   the app.

**What is an App Linking with the example of Facebook**

> When someone shares content from within an app that has Facebook App
>   Links applied, anyone clicking on that link will be able to access
>   that content through the app. This can be done using an app
>   alternative to existing web content, or app-only content, and works
>   either from ‘web to app’ or ‘app to app’. The feature works with
>   Android, iOS and Windows phones

Photo: [image: Example]

Comment: though new some of what you have posted, but thanx anyway. now i have something to know

Answer (score 28):

App Indexing allows Google to crawl your app content (as it would on a website).

**Deep Links vs Android App Links:**

App Links are just deep links that have been verified for a website, *AND* allows opening URLs in the associated app directly without asking the user to select the app (via the disambiguation dialog). With App Links, your app designates itself as the default handler of a given type of link (though the user can override it from device system settings)

A nice overview of the differences is at https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations?authuser=0

Also see comparison table below, lifted from the above link at the time of writing
[image: android-app-links-and-deep-links]