# Send SMS with link to open Android mobile app

Tags: android, url-scheme, android-deep-link

Our cloud application sends SMS reminders to about 50 people (not employees, not strangers, but known close associates). The reminder currently says something along the lines of "Reply Y or N".
Now we have a mobile app in Android that we are planning to distribute to them, and we want to send a reminder that says "Click on the link bbsrep://smsstreamline.bluebridge.com/respond/ and fill in the form".
My problem is that when I install the app onto the device through Android Studio, and then send an SMS to the device saying "Please go to bbsrep://smsstreamline.bluebridge.com/shortreport/", the SMS does not recognise the string as a link.

Is that because the Android Installer from my PC doesn't register the scheme? Or is all my formatting askew?

The complete manifest for the mobile app reads:

````
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bluebridge.smsstreamline">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SMSStreamline">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_senderphone"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Respond"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:host="smsstreamline.bluebridge.com"
                    android:pathPattern=".*"
                    android:pathPrefix="/shortreport/"
                    android:scheme="bbsrep" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>```

I've searched through heaps of SO answers, and tried a dozen different formats, but am too much of a newbie in Java land to work it out.

Jack
````

Comment: I don't think any SMS applications recognises the scheme bbsrep and hence doesn't show as a link, you could try with https if that works for your URL scheme

Comment: But?
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169243/android-uri-schemes-vs-app-links/45173210#45173210) [link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808777/deep-linking-intent-does-not-work?rq=1) [link](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-android-deep-linking-uri-schemes/) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430045/how-to-register-some-url-namespace-myapp-app-start-for-accessing-your-progr/2430468#2430468)

Comment: The above links all show examples of people having done it successfully using a custom scheme.

Comment: you could configure any custom scheme as your URL scheme and launch the app using intent or callbacks from the web, but I highly doubt that a non-https scheme will show as a link in SMS, I believe that's what your question is about

Comment: You have understood my question correctly. But the links I posted all contain comments by people who seem to be saying that they've done it in SMS - that is, included a link which opens an Android app using a custom scheme. I agree that it works with http or https - I guess I'm stuck with that. Thanks for your comments.